# Primefaces dataTable get current page rowcount

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In Primefaces DataTable script to get current page row count **WidgetVar.paginator.cfg.rowCount** it show all rows count but I need current page row count (i.e) first page 20 records and second as 3 records when I click paginator  for 2 second I need result 2 second page row count result 3.

```
<p:ajax event="page" oncomplete="getRowCount();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some small client side jquery javascript where you count the number of `<tr>` tags in the datatable data `<tbody>`

Try this

```
console.log($('#form\\:carTable_data').children());
```

`#form:carTable_data` is the full id of the corresponding body in the [lazy loading showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) where the id of the datatable is `carTable` and the data body gets `_data` appended to it. In jquery the : needs to be escaped with a double backslash if the : is an actual part of the id. Otherwise it is interpreted as a pseudoselector.